# LISTA DE LISTAS, NO REPETIBLES Y COMPLETAS

Tags: python, recursión

Quiero generar una lista de listas, donde cada sub-lista sea una combinacion de 4 elementos (strings) de la variable *opciones*. Cada lista debe ser única, y deben estar todas las opciones posibles (las 360 = 6.5.4.3).

Necesita ser recursivo puesto que si en el futuro se quieren crear sublistas de 5 elementos a partir de 8 opciones distintas, esta funcion *generar_combinaciones()* devuelva todas las combinaciones (las 6720 = 8.7.6.5.4)

```
lugares = 4
opciones = ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'ROSA', 'NARANJA', 'VERDE']

def generar_combinaciones(opciones,combinaciones=[],combinacion=[]):
    
    #opciones        ->  lista de todos los elementos que queda recorrer
    #combinaciones   ->  se guarda en una lista todas las combinaciones de 'lugares' creadas
    #combinacion     ->  cuando la combinacion llegue a 'lugares' elementos se guarda en combinaciones
    
    for opcion in opciones:
        combinacion.append(opcion)
        if len(combinacion) < lugares:
            opciones_restantes = opciones.copy()
            opciones_restantes.remove(opcion)
            aux = generar_combinaciones(opciones_restantes,combinaciones,combinacion)
        else:
            aux = combinacion.copy()
        combinaciones.append(aux)
        combinacion.remove(opcion)
    return combinaciones

todas_las_combinaciones = generar_combinaciones(opciones,combinaciones,combinacion)
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: ¿El orden es importante? ¿Son ["Amarillo", "Rojo"] y ["Rojo", "Amarillo"] la misma combinación o dos distintas?

Answer (score 3):

Primero voy a resolver este problema en forma acotada, sin recursión. Mi objetivo es tener una solución correcta, y luego extenderla a una solución recursiva. Mirando ésta podre crear la otra.

Considerare una cantidad fija de elementos (4) y escribiré explícitamente 4 ciclos anidados.

En cada ciclo intentare agregar un elemento extra al conjunto de cuatro, sin repetirme. Cuando tenga cuatro elementos, los incorporare al resultado final.  Luego de incorporar cada elemento, lo eliminare de la lista para poder agregar el siguiente:

```
lugares = 4
opciones = ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'ROSA', 'NARANJA', 'VERDE']


def generar_combinaciones(opciones, lugares):
    limite = len(opciones)
    lista = []
    cta = 0
    for i1 in range(limite):
        resultado = [opciones[i1]]
        for i2 in range(limite):
            if not opciones[i2] in resultado:
                resultado.append(opciones[i2])
                for i3 in range(limite):
                    if not opciones[i3] in resultado:
                        resultado.append(opciones[i3])
                        for i4 in range(limite):
                            if not opciones[i4] in resultado:
                                resultado.append(opciones[i4])
                            if len(resultado) == lugares:
                                cta += 1
                                #print(cta, resultado)
                                lista.append(resultado.copy())
                                del resultado[-1]
                        del resultado[-1]
                del resultado[-1]
    return lista

lista = generar_combinaciones(opciones, lugares)
cta = 1
for x in lista:
    print(cta, x)
    cta += 1
```

Esto genera 360 combinaciones.

Ahora la solución recursiva, copiando el patrón que usamos en la solución acotada:

```
lugares = 4
opciones = ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'ROSA', 'NARANJA', 'VERDE']


def generar_combinaciones(opciones, lugares, resultado, lista):
    limite = len(opciones)
    for i in range(limite):
        if not opciones[i] in lista:
            lista.append(opciones[i])
            if len(lista) < lugares:
                generar_combinaciones(opciones, lugares, resultado, lista)
                del lista[-1]
            else:
                resultado.append(lista.copy())
                del lista[-1]
    return

resultado = []
lista = []
generar_combinaciones(opciones, lugares, resultado, lista)
cta = 0
for x in resultado:
    cta += 1
    print(cta, x)
```

produce:

```
1 ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'ROSA']
2 ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'NARANJA']
3 ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'VERDE']
...
358 ['VERDE', 'NARANJA', 'ROSA', 'AZUL']
359 ['VERDE', 'NARANJA', 'ROSA', 'AMARILLO']
360 ['VERDE', 'NARANJA', 'ROSA', 'ROJO']
```

Ahora probare seleccionando cinco colores de una lista de ocho:

```
lugares = 5
opciones = ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'ROSA', 'NARANJA', 'VERDE', 'TURQUESA', 'VIOLETA']
```

lo que produce:

```
1 ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'ROSA', 'NARANJA']
2 ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'ROSA', 'VERDE']
3 ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'ROSA', 'TURQUESA']
...
6718 ['VIOLETA', 'TURQUESA', 'VERDE', 'NARANJA', 'AMARILLO']
6719 ['VIOLETA', 'TURQUESA', 'VERDE', 'NARANJA', 'ROJO']
6720 ['VIOLETA', 'TURQUESA', 'VERDE', 'NARANJA', 'ROSA']
```

Nota:
Fue difícil de escribir, no pidan que sea fácil de entender. La recursión nunca es fácil

Answer (score 2):

Lo que estás buscando, son las permutaciones de los elementos de una lista, la forma más sencilla es explotar el módulo [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html) y particularmente la clase [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
from itertools import permutations

opciones = ['AZUL', 'AMARILLO', 'ROJO', 'ROSA', 'NARANJA', 'VERDE']

permutaciones = list(permutations(opciones, 4))
print(len(permutaciones)

360
```

Con el código anterior hemos generado la lista de permutaciones de 360 elementos, un número más que manejable, pero hay que tener cuidado con el `list()`, ya que "materializa" todos los elementos, mientras `permutations()` es una expresión iteradora con lo que realmente los elementos no se "generan" hasta el momento que realmente los necesites:

```
for permutacion in permutations(opciones, 4):
   print(permutacion)
```